# How to hide empty or undefined query parameters in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using Angular2 (RC2) and the new Router (Alpaha.8) How can I stop a query param showing in the URL if it is undefined? Eg.

```
this.router.navigate(["/results", this.month, this.day],
    {
       queryParams: {
          adults: +this.adults
    }
});
```

Sometimes adults may have a value and other times it may not which is when I don't want to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is another way than just *not* to add them when they are undefined:

```
let queryParams:any = {};
if(this.adults) queryParams.adults = this.adults;

this.router.navigate(["/results", this.month, this.day],
    {
       queryParams: queryParams
    }
});
```

Comment: I added 
    `let queryParams: any = {};`

Answer (score 0):

```
let queryParams = { paramToAdd: "newValue", paramToRemove: undefined };

router.navigate(['.'], { queryParams, queryParamsHandling: "merge", relativeTo: this.route.parent })
```